# ereg() to preg_match() how?

Tags: php, preg-match, ereg

I have kind of simple regexes that i am using.

It's so simple as:

```
"user/"
"user/[A-z0-9_-]"
```

These all work fine with ereg, but not preg.

How to convert it?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's most probably because your're missing the [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Try this:

```
"~user/~"
"~user/[A-z0-9_-]~"
```

Comment: What is the point of delimiters? It seems like all the posix regexes works enclosed with those delimiters. To they add functionality or are they syntactic sugar?

Comment: Delimiters makes it possible to add modifiers. You can read more about it at http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 0):

```
ereg('jpg$', $query)
```

Turns into:

```
preg_match('@jpg$@', $query)
```